# Python output numpy array as base64 encoded string instead of jpg

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple Python3 script that is creating an image from a numpy array using the following...

```
cv2.imwrite("finalImage.jpg", numpyArray)
```

This is working correctly but now I am looking to output a base64 encoded string instead of the jpg image.

I know I can convert the output jpg image to a `base64` string but is there a way to do this directly so I can skip the extra step of outputting the JPG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**`imencode(..)`** [opencv-doc]](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode) to write the image to a memory buffer:

```
success, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', numpyArray)
```

You can then for example base64 encode this:

```
from base64 import b64encode

encoded_image = b64encode(buffer)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, perfect solution and works well. Thanks for the links to the doc, reading them, now to make sure I fully understand what is happening

Answer (score 3):

```
import base64
_, imagebytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', numpyArray)
print(base64.b64encode(imagebytes))
```